# Maven building, but not testing

Tags: android, maven, bamboo

We are trying to develop an `Android` application in Eclipse using TDD/Continuous Integration.
We have Maven 3 and Atlassian Bamboo running on a server. Our problem is, that when running `mvn clean install` from cli, Maven builds the App and AppTest successfully, but no tests are run.
Running the sample15demos, we downloaded, Maven builds and runs tests.

Would like help with setup or perhaps an alternative altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Android apps tend to change the test path inside the build tag.
Check that your tests are in the correct directory.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    ...etc etc...
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped, now it run my activitytest. But I need it to do my unit test also. I have extend from AndroidTestCase. And later on I would like it to do Robotium test also.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly my problem after I'd restructured my project.

My tests were moved into src/instrumentTest/java so had to update the build tag to contain

<testSourceDirectory>src/instrumentTest/java</testSourceDirectory>